# Rails 5 Routing - How can I share a common route among many resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have many resources where I want to have a *delete view* before destroying a record, for example:

```
resources :assignments do
    get 'delete'
  end

  resources :occupations do
    get 'delete'
  end

  resources :extra_shifts do
    get 'delete'
  end

  resources :events do
    get 'delete'
  end
```

***Is there a way I can DRY this up?***

I'm aware of [Routing Concerns](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns), but that way I'd just shift the route line outside of the block and set it beside the resources line, which could save some lines but still have lots of duplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty sure

```
resources :assignments, :events,
 :occupations, :extra_shifts do
  get 'delete'
end
```

would work

Comment: That could work, but it's a growing project with around 50 resources with the same dependency, so that line could get pretty large...

Comment: you can split it on to multiple lines (shown above) or into multiple resource statements, but you do need to put the resources somewhere